# exchange server. find users with 'out of office' property equals to 1

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, exchange-server

My idea is to create a VBA script in excel which will check defined users' "out of office" property from exchange server.

[image]

On this picture you see that by pressing Check button VBA script should check only mentioned users in column A. (there are 150 users in company X) And based on their status repopulate their status in column C.

Is it possible? Any ideas how it is possible to connect to exchange server and get this property?

Thank you

Comment: Sure it is possible. Yet, you have been around long enough to know that SO is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. So, do some research and try to come up with some code. This should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450039/excel-vba-getting-a-users-ldap-string-correct Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Ralph thanks for your comment. My only issue was that I don't know if it is possible to connect and get data. I have code where I populate data from excel into outlook calendar :) I was trying to google but found no examples of connection to server ... and what should be property name ... anyway thanks for the link. Hopefully will find some answers there

Comment: The above link queries the LDAP (Active Directory in your network). Of course, it depends on the server settings if you actually get an answer to your inquiry. Furthermore, you'll have to ask your local admin if there is a flag on the LDAP to get the "Status" for user and if this flag can be queried. Here at SO we can only help you with the code. The rest depends on your local network, server, and the admin.

Comment: Ralph yes sure I know how SO works :) And I don't want a lot :) I think I can get status because when I am trying to create email to somebody who had set Out of office I see notification even before sending email. Anyway thank you for ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the Outlook Object Model ([Namespace.CreateRecipient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866418.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) / [Recipient.FreeBusy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869807.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) or [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643673%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).